# Adding characters in values in an existing column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add characters to values in a column.  For example:

```
Price column
22.99
12.95
10.35
```

For my query output, I need this column to show as

```
Price column
Price is 22.99
Price is 12.95
Price is 10.35
```

I already used this to convert these values to char as I think I have to do this to insert characters in this column...

```
CONVERT (char(12), price) AS price
```

I just can't figure out how I can write the command to add "Price is" in every row :(

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Why you want to do this? Add this logic in your application instead. Otherwise, you are going to store twice more symbols in your column (if you have many rows, this is not good idea). Something more, now you are not able to use aggregate functions like SUM/AVG and you can not do things like "SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE Price < 50". Just reconsider this and move your logic in the application or if you really need to do this in the SQL, then use function/view or procedure.

Comment: I think you should add "price is" not in the database but in your code as to why transfer same text with every data row returned. handle it in your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot permanently to do this if the data type of the column is `INT` or *number* but you can do it on `SELECT` statement,

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('Price is ', priceColumn) Price_Column
FROM    tableName
```

In `TSQL`

```
SELECT  'Price is ' + CAST(priceColumn AS VARCHAR(15)) Price_Column
FROM    tableName
```

---

But if you change the data type of that column into string (`VARCHAR()`) then you can simple execute `UPDATE` command

In `MySQL`,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     priceColumn = CONCAT('Price is ', priceColumn)
```

in `TSQL`

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     priceColumn = 'Price is ' + CAST(priceColumn AS VARCHAR(15))
```

Comment: Here's my current SQL statement:
SELECT title_id, 
  LEFT(title, 30 ) AS title,
  CONVERT (char(12), price) AS price,
  advance, 
  pubdate,
  CONVERT( char(12), pubdate,106) AS pubdate

FROM TITLES
WHERE ADVANCE >= '5000'
AND  PUBDATE in ('06/12/1991' , '06/30/1991')
ORDER BY TITLE

Where do I insert this statement:
 SELECT  'Price is ' + CAST(priceColumn AS VARCHAR(15)) Price_Column

Comment: what RDBMS you are using? MySQL or SQLServer? they are two different things.

Comment: CONCAT('Price is ', priceColumn) Price_Column

This one actually worked without converting the data type to varchar.  The column originally had money as the data type and I had to convert it to char  CONVERT (char(12), price) AS price  thinking I have to do that before I can insert any texts in the column.  

However, using this alone worked! :)   
CONCAT('Price is ', price) price

Thank you so much!